# Include game title in title of question?

Tags: support, tags, asking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question with Vague title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title)

Kind of a silly question but I never know if I should include the game title in the question title or simply provide the game title in the subject and tag.  What should I be doing?