# Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, title-tag

I searched through Meta and couldn't find an answer to this. I was reviewing my questions this morning and I noticed that in certain questions like [What is the effect of falling to your death in Metroid Prime 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/what-is-the-effect-of-falling-to-your-death-in-metroid-prime-3), the `<title>` tag on that page shows:

> metroid prime corruption - What is the effect of falling to your death in Metroid Prime 3? - Gaming - Stack Exchange

So it's like the first tag (`s/-/ /g`) is prepended to the question title to make up the `<title>` tag. Why is this? Because it happens [here also](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12454/in-world-of-goo-how-do-you-get-ocd-on-impale-sticky), and [on meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title), but it [does not](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/how-do-i-earn-money-skill-points-in-tiger-woods-pga-tour-10-for-wii) [happen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/any-way-to-extract-music-from-nintendo-wii-games) [always](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/what-does-it-mean-when-a-ghost-has-appeared-in-a-galaxy-in-super-mario-galaxy-2).

What is causing this behavior and where can I read more about it? (Or should I ask on Mother Meta?)

**EDIT:** Now with Freehand Circles:

[image: FHC FTW]

Comment: Ask on Meta Stack Overflow. This is occurring everywhere. It's also not necessarily the first tag. I haven't quite figured the method behind it.

Comment: Upvote for Freehand Circles. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Grace Note's suggestion I want ahead and [asked on the mother of all meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions) where a friendly gal named Rebecca gave me a nearly instant answer. I'll update this answer as more appear.

> In order to try and stop the scrapers
>   from being ranked higher on Google,
>   they are working on increasing their
>   SEO.  To this end, the tag listed
>   first on a question (sorted by
>   popularity of the tag) will now appear
>   at the start of the page title. 
>   Search engines like having keywords in
>   the page title, specifically at the
>   beginning of the page title.  If the
>   tag is already in the title, then this
>   new approach won't duplicate the
>   keyword, as you've noticed with
>   several of your links.
>
> I've asked a related
>   [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6556/46)
>   about the ordering of keywords on
>   Webmasters.

Also, Benjamin Dumke, ([Stack Overflow Valued Associate #00007](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007), better known as [balpha ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) or Lord of the Chats) confirmed this and offered  more explanation:

> "seems like if the tag is already in the title, it won't duplicate it" -- that's correct. – balpha♦

Comment: Don't forget [balpha's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) comment, which confirms that the tag being in the title is why it isn't in all question titles.

Comment: @Grace the comments are coming in faster than I can read/respond to everything! Meta is such a crazy house, *Aieeeee!* :-)