# Why was this question's title reverted to be in the '[tag] - [question title]' format?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions, asking

This is regarding this question which is currently titled: [MU online - are there accumulated benefits to raising stamina early in the game for high HP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375430/mu-online-are-there-accumulated-benefits-to-raising-stamina-early-in-the-game)

I have previously [changed the title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/375430/revisions#rev-arrow-58e36fea-7a5c-4275-99fe-7056bae4c15e) of the question to 'Are there accumulated benefits to raising stamina early in the game for high HP?', removing the '*[tag] -* ' in the question title and [added the game name in the question body](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/375430/revisions#rev-arrow-58e36fea-7a5c-4275-99fe-7056bae4c15e) but a mod [reverted the edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/375430/revisions#rev-arrow-5148d0e0-b5c4-47f3-a5fc-746890d7dc28) back to its initial revision which is in the '*[tag] - [question title]*' format.

My edit was in accordance with the SE network-wide Meta FAQ post, [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/162827)

> **...it is completely unnecessary to include tags in your question titles.**

and that:

> The only time you should use tags in your title is when *they are
> organic to the conversational tone of the title*.
>
> For example,
>
> > JavaScript, jQuery:  When should I use one or the other?
>
> is seen by many users as an attempt to force tags in order to
> compensate for a lousy title. The title would be much more
> well-received if rewritten like this:
>
> > Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or is my only choice to use plain JavaScript?

Keywords here are 'organic' and 'conversational'. The [tag] - [question title] format is awkward, and both non-organic and non-conversational.

And as per *multiple* Arqade Meta posts:

[Best Practices: Titles and Tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/4797) (emphasis mine)

> I'm not entirely fond of the process of putting the tags at the front
> of the question title, as a categorizing measure. Firstly, that's what
> tags are meant to do in the first place, we don't need to section off
> the front of the title for that purpose. Second, the new feature in
> which the most popular tag is prepended to the page title also makes
> it look exceptionally awkward. **You get things like "pc - Civilization
> IV:" before you reach the actual title of the question! In that
> scenario, I'm fine with the removal.**
>
> But it's not forbidden to put the tags in the title. Rather, it's
> better to do it organically - make it a *part of the title, rather than
> a preface*.

[When should we edit game names out of question titles? And why? (answer 1)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6951/4797) (emphasis mine)

> Game names in titles are not necessary, as the name is already in a
> tag. The general guidelines is to **avoid putting tags in the title,
> unless the tag fits in naturally.**

[When should we edit game names out of question titles? And why? (answer 2)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6952/4797)

> We don't want to have all question titles look like "Metal Gear Solid 3: how can I jump?" (why would we have tags to begin with, then?), so this is why we prefer typically to leave the game name out of the question.

[Should we include the game name in questions titles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9766/4797) (emphasis mine)

> Titles do not have to contain the name of the game, and **you shouldn't
> intentionally edit a question just to add the game name to the title.**
> ...
> This isn't to say that the game name should *never* be in the title
> question. But you shouldn't be adding the game name to the title
> *just* to add the game name to the title.

[Why are my questions having the game name added to the title?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13581/4797)

> ... the [general](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9766) [established](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/824) norm is not to add titles
> to the name of a question, because tags are already picked up by
> google searches, used to help filter related questions when asking a
> new question, and I believe used to populate the related questions
> tab. So the only real benefit would be if the question goes to HNQ
> people can see which game it is about without navigating to it. Given
> those reasons, it is pretty redundant to add the name of the game to
> the title, and just adds clutter.

I can find no meta posts which suggest that the '*[tag] - [question title]'* format is the preferred title format by the community. In fact, this is the only SE site I know where question titles are edited to be in the awkward '[tag] - [question title]' format, and by a mod nonetheless.

Answer (score -7):

### Why was the title of this one question intentionally changed to a bad format?

It wasn't. An edit that made the title less clear was reverted. The title before the edit is bad, but still better than after the edit. Ideally, the title should be edited to be clear and attract subject matter experts without having to click through.

### What about the policy to remove all games from titles?

There is no such policy.

As per the SE network-wide Meta FAQ post, [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/370674)

> The only time you should use tags in your title is when *they are organic to the conversational tone of the title*.

And [Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180100/370674)

> **Titles should be completely independent of tags. A good title tells an expert whether they want to read the full question all by itself.**
>
> [...]
>
> - **I agree that we should never force a tag into a title if it's not helpful;** https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33812/why-didnt-my-beer-cake-cook-properly should NOT have "[Baking]:" jammed into the title, because it adds nothing to a reader's understanding of what it's about, BUT...
> - **Nothing should be left out of a title just because it exists in the tags.**

And on our own Meta:

[Best Practices: Titles and Tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/143571)

> But it's not forbidden to put the tags in the title. Rather, it's better to do it organically - make it a part of the title, rather than a preface. Use terminology like "In Chaos Wars, how do I recruit Emily?" or "How do I shoot down spy planes in Black Ops?", if you want to stick things in the title. This is especially important with otherwise generic titles or when the specific tag really helps.
>
> [...]
>
> Ultimately, the title and the tags are meant to work in concert. So it's not required to stick it in the title if you feel the title doesn't need it. But if it organically fits, I don't think it's completely necessary to remove it.

[When should we edit game names out of question titles? And why?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6950/143571)

> In cases like this, where the question itself is completely generic and applies to many games, adding the title perfectly acceptable, it might be even necessary to circumvent the duplicate title check (you can't have two questions with exactly the same title on the site).

[Should we include the game name in questions titles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9765/143571)

> This isn't to say that the game name should never be in the title question. But you shouldn't be adding the game name to the title *just* to add the game name to the title. You should have some other compelling reason to do it, as outlined in Jaydles's answer.

That answer saying

> **You should include the game in the question title anytime it's needed to determine if you would want to read the question.**

### Isn't that redundant with tags?

If titles were always accompanied by tags, yes. There are many places where one can find the title of a question without its tags, such as:

- The "Related" questions list when reading a question
- The "Hot Network Questions" list on most pages of the main site
- Direct links to other questions, like in this very answer
- The "Similar questions" list when writing a question
- The list of duplicates when a question is closed

Claiming that titles don't need to be properly descriptive because the information can be found in the tags is ignoring most ways to reach a question that are not the main page or the search results.

Comment: I believe you've misinterpreted what I'm trying to say in my post. I'm not saying that there's a 'policy to remove all games from titles' and that 'titles don't need to be properly descriptive'. I'm saying that the policy is *not* to put titles in the [tag] - [title] format. The common theme from all the meta posts I've quoted is that tags in a question title should either be not in the title, or: if tags *have* to be put in the title then they *have* to be *organic* and *conversational* to the tone of the title. The '[tag] - [question title]' format is anything but organic and conversational.

Comment: But changing the title to not contain the game at all is worse than having it in this bad format, as I've mentioned in the answer. I simply reverted a harmful edit.