# Should question titles be edited to better reflect the content of the question?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question with Vague title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title)

I've come across a number of question titles that would be vague on their own:

- [How dangerous is it to explore aimlessly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42244/how-dangerous-is-it-to-explore-aimlessly)
- [Can I log onto an
  existing account through steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75310/can-i-log-onto-an-existing-tribes-ascend-account-through-steam)
- [What are some good heroes for a beginner?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64073/what-are-some-good-heroes-for-a-beginner)

The questions refer to Breath of Death VII, Tribes: Ascend and DOTA 2 respectively, as you can clearly see in the question's content and its tags. I usually feel like a more descriptive question title is better, so I edited the Tribes: Ascend question. On other StackExchange sites, it generally seems that a more specific question title is preferred, rather than simply relying on the tags and question content.

Answer (score 7):

The most-used tag will be automatically added in front of the title for the HTML title, which is e.g. displayed in search engine results.

So, I generally would not add the game name to titles, this will automatically happen for those places where it is important. My personal exception is for very short titles where you can add the name of the game organically, without having to mutilate the title or making it so long it'll be displayed on two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to see titles that are clearly incorrect edited to reflect the actual question - there have been occasions when the question was different and user has another problem in the actual description; but I am hesitant to update question myself due to lack of Arqade experience (and its hard to flag these; everything is valid except for misleading title!)

As for this discussion;imho no need to edit if the tags add the required context or it is easily obtained from the description. If a reader has to go through several paragraphs to figure out the intent, then yes the title should be edited.