# Include the game in the question title so that it's clearer in the Hot Network Questions list

Tags: discussion, questions, hot-network-questions

Suggestion: make all questions look like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394813/fifa-2022-unable-to-play-online-matches-on-nintendo-switch-was-working-fine-f) where it's apparent from the title which game is being discussed.

Reason is because it makes it clear from the HNQ list whether or not to look at the question.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title) post. I think historically it's never been necessary to include the tag in the title, but if someone does, it's generally fine.

Comment: The onus shouldn't be on individual sites to remember to put things that are tags in their title - it should be up to SE to add that functionality to the HNQ sidebar. We're not the only site with question titles that are weird without including the tags.

Comment: @Robotnik it's not realistic to put all the tags on the HNQ sidebar. There is simply no space.

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* - To all parties: Lets keep this conversation friendly, constructive and on-topic. Remember the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: See the SE Meta FAQ post: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/162827) - It explains why the policy is to not include tags (game names, in this case) in question titles.

Comment: This might be of interest: the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/10706) userscript has this feature: "When hovering over a question title in the Hot Network Questions sidebar, the question's tags from the originating site will be shown."

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary to include the name of the game in the question since your question needs to be tagged for the game itself, and that is shown right under your question.

[image]

You can put the name of the game in the question if you want, but it is not necessary.

Comment: When you see a question under the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) tab on the right of the screen, you can't also see the tags. You only see the title, and which SE it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a reason to cater to HNQ when Arqade itself functions fine...

Comment: @nightsurfer in that case, I suggest telling SE to never list an Arqade question on HNQ.

Comment: @Allure Why, what would that accomplish? Have you gone to every SE and asked that extremely verbose information be put in the title? Should every question on Android Enthusiasts SE  contain the exact version number or the device it runs on? Should every question on Super User contain the exact operating system number and device it runs on? It's extraneous information that really serves no purpose.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what HNQ you're looking at, but the Desktop Site already has tags under each question?

Answer (score 4):

Questions in HNQ list should have an appealing and catchy title to attract people, since it's why it was created (I suppose), adding the game name will.. ruin the magic.
Moreover, we have a tradition for vague and funny questions here on Arqade, so I see no benefits doing that for every post.

Comment: “We have a tradition for vague and funny questions here” -> [How Do You Kill Children](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37257/124566) is one of my favorites

Comment: @Wondercricket and this is mine: [My children are useless. What should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18376/87579)

Answer (score 1):

Hot Network Questions on the desktop site for SE already shows tags underneath all questions that show up:

[image]

There isn't an Arqade question in the top 50 at this time, so I can't confirm that our tags are also showing up, but considering the evidence, I would assume game tags would show up for Arqade questions that reach HNQ.

Comment: No, it doesn't. https://imgur.com/cvy4EdM

Comment: Then why suggest it for Arqade to do so, if not to go to all SE's and request the same? It sounds like your time might be better spent petitioning Meta SE to add tags to that side-list of hot questions.

Comment: Because the questions on Arqade vary wildly in scope. People who play X game might know nothing about Y; in fact Y might not even interest them. This does not apply to most other SEs. And if you're serious about petitioning Meta SE to add tags to all their questions, feel free.

Comment: @Allure That's your fight, I have no stake in whether there's tags or not. I hardly pay any attention to HNQ as it is. I have the stacks I like to check, and that's it. Things vary wildly in scope on Android Enthusiasts, Workplace, Super User, Worldbuilding, etc as well. Your scope is too narrow in asking Arqade to do this.

Comment: No, that's what you think is my fight. I don't actually believe in it. *I hardly pay any attention to HNQ as it is*. Good for you, but not everyone thinks that way.